# Вывести на экран элементы, которые являются квадратами какого-либо числа

Tags: python, массивы

Дан целочисленный двумерный массив, размерности n х
m. Вывести на экран элементы, которые являются квадратами
какого-либо числа.
У меня получилось написать код для вывода двумерного массива. Но далее нужно каким-то образом осуществить проверку каждого элемента-являются ли они квадратами какого-либо числа.
У меня выводится ошибка:TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

```
from math import sqrt
from random import randint
n, m = 3, 3
a = [[randint(1, 10) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
print (*a,sep='\n')
for k in range (0,m):
 for l in range (0,n):
    if sqrt(a[k,l])==round(a[k,l]):
       print(a[k,l])
```

Comment: `a[l][k]`. Обратите внимание на порядок индексов. И не массив, а список.

Comment: и кроме того, тут совершенно неправильная проверка на квадрат.

Comment: А если числа от 1 до 10, то можно просто в лоб проверить, на равенство 1, 4 или 9  Но это, конечно, плохо масштабируемый код. Зато быстрее

Comment: Я просто для примера ввел диапазон от 1 до 10, на самом деле он может быть любым.

Answer (score 0):

Вам @MBo справедливо отметил, что вы неверно обращаетесь к элементам двухмерного списка.

Кроме того, вы можете обращаться к ним напрямую, а не через индексы:

```
from math import sqrt, modf
from random import randint
n, m = 3, 3
a = [[randint(1, 10) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if modf(sqrt(j))[0] == 0:
            print(j)
```

> 1
> 1
> 4
> 1
> 4

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал, что к элементам можно обращаться напрямую, а не только через индексы.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы перепутали ширину и высоту массива.
2. В индексы передаёте два значения через запятую, Питон не поддерживает такое обращение. Нужно использовать [k][l] вместо [k, l].
3. Вы забыли написать корень в сравнении

Код, который у меня получился:

```
from math import sqrt 
from random import randint
n, m = 3, 5
a = [[randint(1, 10) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
print(*a, sep='\n')

for k in range(n):
    for l in range(m):
        if sqrt(a[k][l]) == round(sqrt(a[k][l])):
            print(a[k][l])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь я понял свою ошибку)